# Syntax Error: line 0, col 152: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'BETWEEN'

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, symfony, symfony4

When I try the following code:

```php
return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->select('e.user_id', 'e.year', 'e.week_number', 'e.approved_by')
    ->where('e.user_id = :userID')
    ->andWhere('(e.year * 100 + e.week_number) BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
    ->setParameter('userID', $userID)
    ->setParameter('startDate', ($startYear * 100 + $startWeek))
    ->setParameter('endDate', ($endYear * 100 + $endWeek))
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

I get the error `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 149: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'BETWEEN'`.

If I print my query, it looks like this:

```sql
dql: "SELECT e.user_id, e.year, e.week_number, e.approved_by FROM App\Entity\... e WHERE e.user_id = :userID AND ((e.year * 100 + e.week_number) BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate)"
```

If I use this query in SSMS and replace the variables with the actual data. It all works perfectly fine.

My variables are have the following value:

```php
$startYear = 2021;
$startWeek = 52;
$endYear = 2022;
$endWeek = 05;

// :startDate = 202152;
// :endDate = 202205;
```

The **calculations** probably break the query builder. Mostly because I do similar query's: `->andWhere('e.week_number between :startWeek and :endWeek')` that do indeed work. I don't know how to fix them or why this happens.

Im using Symfony 4.4. SQL Server for my database.

Comment: Any chance you can use a stored procedure instead of this query builder? Would give you better separation of layers and would eliminate this error.

Comment: @SeanLange I can use native SQL in Symfony. But with that I could just as good put the whole query in it. I have the feeling something is wrong with the query builder, so I wondered if other people might know why or/and how to fix this within the query builder.

Comment: You may try to change the `BETWEEN` condition with `->andWhere('(e.year * 100 + e.week_number) >= :startDate')` and `->andWhere('(e.year * 100 + e.week_number) <= :endDate')`

Comment: @Zhorov Do you post your comment as an answer? So I can accept it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment of Zhorov fixed my problem.

> You may try to change the `BETWEEN` condition with `->andWhere('(e.year * 100 + e.week_number) >= :startDate')` and `->andWhere('(e.year * 100 + e.week_number) <= :endDate')`

Still quite weird the query builder can't handle it. I mean not much has changed and SQL Server itself finds it all good. If someone can explain how this works, I probably vote it as an answer.